# htaccess trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /dir/index.php?category=$1&link=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/dir/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

I'm having a problem with this one, I hope someone will help me.

```
www.domain.com/dir/category/
```

works well, but when it comes to a second variable

```
www.domain.com/dir/category/variable/
```

it doesn't work, but if I remove the last slash, it works...

**EDIT----------------------------**

This works fine so far.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /dir/index.php?category=$1&link=$2 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.omain.com/dir/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where is this htaccess ? is it in /dir ?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the first `RewriteRule` by this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /dir/index.php?category=$1&link=$2 [L]
```

This explicitly allows a trailing slash at the end.

Comment: Add rewrite conditions before the rule to not rewrite if the requested file exists (see my updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /dir/index.php?category=$1&link=$2 [L]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)([^\.css|\.js])/?$ /dir/index.php?category=$1&link=$2$3 [NC,L]
```

**EDIT** This is a massive cop out and I will hopefully update this at some point with a single line rule that does everything, but for now this will work (my brain is not working properly any more). This assumes that your JS is in a directory called 'js' and CSS is in a directory called 'css'. The order of these rules is important!

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/(.*)$ /dir/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /dir/index.php?category=$1&link=$2 [L]
```

Comment: What do your js/css links look like (the contents of the `src`/`href` attributes)?

Comment: nop, can't open categories and get variables.. not found. css worked but it didn't show images

Comment: Yeh I know, I have just been playing with it... I am just going to have to refresh my Regex'ing, not done any mod_rewrite this complicated for a while... I'll get back to you in 5 mins...

Comment: See latest edit. If I can work out a better solution, I will get back to you.

Comment: everything works except css and js. can't list folder content too. and yes, 'js' and 'css' are dirs

Comment: What if you add a leading slash `/` to both rules?

Comment: Where are these rules placed? in a .htaccess in the `/dir` directory?

Comment: This seems odd that the original rule should break your css then... Since your `/css` etc directories is outside the `/dir` directory, the requests for CSS etc files should never end up running through these rules... are there any rules in a .htaccess in the root directory?

Comment: no, there aren't any. css and js folders are located in dir directory.

Comment: Internal Server Error - this is what came up when tried to look at css file.

Comment: I'm very sorry about this, but I'm giving up on this for this evening. I don't understand why it isn't working and I have been staring at it for too long. I will pick this up again in the morning (if you haven't sorted it by then) and I'm sure we can come up with something.

Comment: I think I found a solution... works fine so far... I hope. See my edited post

Comment: Good, glad you got it sorted, I have been playing around with some things [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and realised that I *really* need to refresh my Regex skills, I have forgotten how to do a lot of fairly simple things!